# Receive iBeacon with Same uuid and different major, minor in background

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, bluetooth, ibeacon

I want to show LocalNotification when device enter some beacon range in background.
When device enter the range of Beacon:A (UUID:xxx major:1 minor:1), LocalNotification shows correctly, but after this, when device enter the range of Beacon:B(UUID:xxx major:2 minor:2), nothing happened.
Does didDetermineState not call when device already entered the range of same UUID in background state ?
Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: How are you instantiating your `CLBeaconRegion`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you are monitoring on a single `CLBeaconRegion` without specifying all of the identifiers.  If you do this:

`CLBeaconRegion *region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid major:major identifier:@"myRegion"]]];`

Or this:

`CLBeaconRegion *region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid identifier:@"myRegion"]];`

Then iOS will only notify you once when it sees **either** of the beacons.  By not specifying the minor in your regions, then you are telling iOS to treat all beacons as part of a single region regardless of minor value.

If you want to get separate state notifications for each beacon, construct two different regions like this:

`CLBeaconRegion *regionForBeaconA = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid major:major minor:1 identifier:@"myRegionForBeaconA"]];`

`CLBeaconRegion *regionForBeaconB = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid major:major minor:2 identifier:@"myRegionForBeaconB"]];`

And start monitoring on both regions.  Then you will get a different callback for both Beacon A and Beacon B.